# How to create a smart folder for files created in the last 5 minutes

Tags: finder, smart-folders

I have a camera setup were the camera automatically takes pictures every x seconds and these images are saved in a directory called 'Images'. Now I want to create a smart folder that looks in 'Images' and only lists images that were added in the last 5 minutes. When creating a smart folder, I see only the option the list files from the last day.

**How can I create a smart folder that lists only files created in the last 5 minutes?**

In other words, I want to create a smart folder using non-standard options.

Comment: Don't know about smart folder, but you can always make a regular folder and have a script running in background which makes symlinks to 5 newest images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 'Smart folder' is in principle a XML formatted file that, when opened, returns a Spotlight search result. To create a Smart folder you can add multiple search terms by pressing the `+` (or <kbd>alt</kbd>`+`). For example, you can choose to only return files that where created in the last 7 days. Although there is a profusion of search terms, some are still missing (like searching within the last 5 minutes).

The commandline version of Spotlight is `mdfind` ([manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html)). Although harder to use, `mdfind` commands are more flexable than the Smart folder/Spotlight alternative. You can, for example, search for files that were created in the last 5 minutes like this:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSCreationDate > "$time.now(-300)"'
```

Or were changed in the last 10 minutes:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSContentChangeDate > "$time.now(-600)"'
```

Fortunatly Smart folders support the `mdfind` command! To use `mdfind` search commands do the following:

1. Go to Finder and press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to start a new Smart folder.
2. In the search-items bar you can select 'Other...' from the drop down menu. Search for 'Raw query' and add it to your search terms
3. Now enter your `mdfind` search query in the empty text field

   ```
   kMDItemFSCreationDate > $time.now(-600)
   ```
4. Save your search and you are done.

[image: Other dropdown menu smart folder]
[image: Smart folder raw query]