# Finder search multiple file types

Tags: finder, search

I want to create a Smart Search Folder that will contain `.xcproj` *or* `.xcworkspace` files. I have no problem spefying a single of them, but how do I search for both in the same search?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135705/88313).

Answer (score 1):

After the initial link from fsb to [How to create a smart folder for files created in the last 5 minutes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135705/how-to-create-a-smart-folder-for-files-created-in-the-last-5-minutes) I've went ahead and created a custom expression. For reference, this is the custom query that I've used:

`kMDItemFSName == *.xcodeproj ||kMDItemFSName == *.xcworkspace`